# Not able to perform Query Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

i want to rotate my table horizontally -

The tables are as follows:

Master_Choicecode

```
ChoiceCode      MainCourseId    CourseLevelId    InstituteId
```

Master_MainCourse

```
MainCourseId     MainCourseName   CourseLevelId   CourseProgram
   11                x                1             abc
   12                y                2             xyz
```

Master_CourseLevel

```
CourseLevelId    CourseLevelName     
   1                deg
   2                Dip
```

Master_Institute

```
Instituteid     InstituteName    Statusid
    1001           Insti1          100
    1002           Insti2          200
```

Master_InstituteStatus

```
StatusId   StatusName
  100            Status1
  200            Status2
```

Now using all these tables i want to show this:

```
CourseProgram   CourseLevelName  Status1(from Master_InstituteStatus)     Status2(from Master_InstituteStatus)    
    abc             Deg          Count of institutes belonging to status1  Count of institutes belonging to status2
```

Now this is what i have tried:

```
SELECT B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName,
case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status1' then COUNT(*) else null end as     Status1,
case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status2' then COUNT(*) else null  end as  Status2,
FROM Master_ChoiceCode A 
inner join Master_MainCourse B on A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
inner join Master_CourseLevel C on A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
inner join  Master_Institute D on A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
inner join Master_InstituteStatus1 E on D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
where B.CourseLevelID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY B.CourseProgram,A.CourseLevelID,C.CourseLevelName,E.InstituteStatusName
order by B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName;
```

But with this i get the output like this:

```
CourseProgram   CourseLevelName  Status1(from Master_InstituteStatus)     Status2(from Master_InstituteStatus)    
    abc             Deg          Count of institutes belonging to status1  
    abc             Deg                      Null                              Count of institutes belonging to status1
```

i got the solution to this is to use pivot...but i dont knw how shal i use Pivot with my current query.Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but grouping on `E.InstituteStatusName` means you will not be able to combine the data onto one row. Rather than use the `case` statement with a `count`, you could use a conditional sum.

```
SELECT B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status1' then 1 else 0 end) as     Status1,
sum(case when E.InstituteStatusName =' Status2' then 1 else 0 end) as  Status2,
FROM Master_ChoiceCode A 
inner join Master_MainCourse B on A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
inner join Master_CourseLevel C on A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
inner join  Master_Institute D on A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
inner join Master_InstituteStatus1 E on D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
where B.CourseLevelID IN(1,2)
GROUP BY B.CourseProgram,A.CourseLevelID,C.CourseLevelName
order by B.CourseProgram,C.CourseLevelName;
```

This will effectively count the rows matching that status without the need for grouping on that field.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in PIVOT function in SQL-Server:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  B.CourseProgram,
            C.CourseLevelName, 
            E.InstituteStatusName,
            b.CourseLevelID
    FROM    Master_ChoiceCode A 
            INNER JOIN Master_MainCourse B 
                ON A.MainCourseID=B.MainCourseID
            INNER JOIN Master_CourseLevel C 
                ON A.CourseLevelID=C.CourseLevelID  
            INNER JOIN  Master_Institute D 
                ON A.InstituteID=D.InstituteID
            INNER JOIN Master_InstituteStatus1 E 
                ON D.InstituteStatusID1=E.InstituteStatusID
    WHERE   B.CourseLevelID IN (1,2)
)
SELECT  CourseProgram, CourseLevelName, [Status1], [Status2]
FROM    CTE
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(CourseLevelID)
            FOR InstituteStatusName IN ([Status1], [Status2])
        ) pvt

ORDER BY CourseProgram, CourseLevelName;
```